# Python 2.7 current row index on 2d array iteration

Tags: python-2.7, multidimensional-array

When iterating on a 2d array, how can I get the current row index? For example:

```
x = [[ 1.  2.  3.  4.]
     [ 5.  6.  7.  8.]
     [ 9.  0.  3.  6.]]
```

Something like:

```
for rows in x:
   print x current index (for example, when iterating on [ 5.  6.  7.  8.], return 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Enumerate** is a built-in function of Python. It’s usefulness can not be summarized in a single line. Yet most of the newcomers and even some advanced programmers are unaware of it. It allows us to loop over something and have an automatic counter. Here is an example:

```
for counter, value in enumerate(some_list):
    print(counter, value)
```

And there is more! enumerate also accepts an optional argument which makes it even more useful.

```
my_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'grapes', 'pear']
for c, value in enumerate(my_list, 1):
    print(c, value)
```

.

```
# Output:
# 1 apple
# 2 banana
# 3 grapes
# 4 pear
```

The optional argument allows us to tell enumerate from where to start the index. You can also create tuples containing the index and list item using a list. Here is an example:

```
my_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'grapes', 'pear']
counter_list = list(enumerate(my_list, 1))
print(counter_list)
```

.

```
# Output: [(1, 'apple'), (2, 'banana'), (3, 'grapes'), (4, 'pear')]
```

Answer (score 0):

[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
    In [42]: x = [[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
    ...:          [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
    ...:          [ 9,  0,  3,  6]]

In [43]: for index, rows in enumerate(x):
    ...:     print('current index {}'.format(index))
    ...:     print('current row {}'.format(rows))
    ...:
current index 0
current row [1, 2, 3, 4]
current index 1
current row [5, 6, 7, 8]
current index 2
current row [9, 0, 3, 6]
```